# How to avoid #NUM! values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that does certain calculation based on the range provided.

The problem is, if the range doesn't have any value then it displays "#NUM!" in the destination cell. Instead, I want to display it as "0"

My code is :

```
Sub TPTrailNoRedpass99tablet()

 Dim cel As Range
 Dim Rng As Range
 Dim arr As Variant
 Dim i As Long
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       For Each cel In Sheets("TP").Range("A3:D30")
           If cel.Font.Color = 0 Then
                If Rng Is Nothing Then
   Set Rng = cel
                Else
   Set Rng = Union(cel, Rng)
                End If
                End If
                Next cel
   ReDim arr(Rng.count - 1)
             If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                  For Each cel In Rng
                         arr(i) = cel
                         i = i + 1
   Next cel
  Sheets("TP").Range("PH1").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1).Value =    Application.Transpose(arr)
  Set Rng = Sheets("TP").Range("PH1:PH" & Sheets("TP").Cells(Rows.count, "PH").End(xlUp).Row)
  Sheets("WBR").Range("AH111").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC(" & Rng.Address(, , , True) & ",99%)*24"
  Sheets("WBR").Range("AH111").Value = Sheets("WBR").Range("AH111").Value
  Sheets("TP").Columns("PH:PH").ClearContents

  End If

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use `Cells.Replace` to replace `#NUM! with 0` in worksheet

```
Cells.Replace "#NUM!","0",xlWhole
```

Comment: After this `Sheets("TP").Columns("PH:PH").ClearContents` put   `Cells.Replace "#NUM!","0",xlWhole`

Comment: @FordHarrison - Why have you marked this as the answer? It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two sensible approaches to this.

Either make your formula handle the error correctly. You can do that simply like this:

```
Sheets("WBR").Range("AH111").Formula = "=IFERROR(PERCENTILE.INC(" & Rng.Address(, , , True) & ",99%),0)"
```

Or, if you want to do it in VBA, then, after the line `Sheets("WBR").Range("AH111").Formula = ...` do this:

```
If WorksheetFunction.IsError(Sheets("WBR").Range("AH111").Value) Then
    Sheets("WBR").Range("AH111").Value = 0
End If
```

Comment: Your first method would be easier written using the formula `... = "=IFERROR(PERCENTILE.INC(" & Rng.Address(, , , True) & ",99%)*24,0)"` - that would avoid Excel having to calculate the main part of the formula twice.

Comment: @YowE3K - I must admit that I didn't know that function was there. I have been using this version since Excel V2.